# Formatting Field values using itextsharp

Tags: itext

how can i have a string format "i am **fine** here" using itextsharp
fields.SetField("tgPara2", message2);
where message is "i am **fine** here" i want the fine word only to be bold.
Any help would be

Answer (score 0):

iText has partial support for "rich text values" for text fields.  You can get and set the rich values, but iText won't actually *draw* those values properly.  You need to turn off `SetGenerateAppearances`, and open the PDF in Acrobat/Reader to see the rich text.

This means flattening isn't going to work (unless you open the PDF in Acrobat, then save it again... clunky).

You might want to check out the [PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (Section 12..7.3.4 Rich Text Strings) for further information on what is and isn't legal.  `<b>` is legal, as is the `font-weight` CSS style